WebSocket Connection Error on Remote Server with Ocelot API Gateway: Unable to connect to the remote server, SSL Handshake Issues
I am encountering an issue with establishing a WebSocket connection through Ocelot API Gateway when deploying to a remote IIS server. The connection works fine locally, but when trying to connect remotely, I get the following error:
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan1 buffer)at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Problem Context:
I’m using Ocelot API Gateway to proxy WebSocket connections to a remote WebSocket server.
The server is hosted on IIS, and WebSocket connections are working perfectly fine when running locally (on the same machine).
However, when attempting to connect via Ocelot on the remote IIS server, I’m getting the SSL/TLS handshake error, which results in the Unable to connect to the remote server exception.
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan1 buffer)at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)...`

We tried setting up WebSocket Protocol on IIS Server.

Allow WebSocket Protocol in IIS.
Install WebSocket Protocol
Enable WebSocket in the IIS Configuration

This still didn't resolve the handshake issue.
Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
